# Unregistered task in Celery

Tags: celery, celery-task

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
from django.http import HttpResponse
from anyjson import serialize

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//')

#@celery.task
def add(request):
    x = int(request.GET['x'])
    y = int(request.GET['y'])
    result = x+y
    response = {'status': 'success', 'retval': result}
    return HttpResponse(serialize(response), mimetype='application/json')
```

after starting the worker,i tried http dispatcher:

```
from celery.task.http import URL
res = URL('http://localhost/add').get_async(x=10, y=10)
res.state
'PENDING'
```

and got error like,
[2013-04-03 06:39:54,791: ERROR/MainProcess] Received unregistered task of type u'celery.task.http.HttpDispatchTask'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you are using relative imports?
More: http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#names

The full contents of the message body was:
`{u'utc': True, u'chord': None, u'args': [u'http://localhost/add', u'GET'], u'retries': 0, u'expires': None, u'task': u'celery.task.http.HttpDispatchTask', u'callbacks': None, u'errbacks': None, u'taskset': None, u'kwargs': {u'y': 10, u'x': 10}, u'eta': None, u'id': u'29f83cc9-ba5a-4008-9d2d-6f7bb24b0cfc'} (288b)`

Traceback (most recent call last):
`File "/usr/local/gdp/python2.7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery-3.0.13-py2.7.egg/celery/worker/consumer.py", line 435, in on_task_received
    strategies[name](message, body, message.ack_log_error)
KeyError: u'celery.task.http.HttpDispatchTask'`

Answer (score 1):

Apologies if I'm stating the obvious, but the task decorator `#@celery.task` is commented out.